# Create a xml having horizontal scrollview in it?

Tags: android, xml, horizontalscrollview

I want to create a horizontal scroll view . I have seen many tutorials giving me the details ,but my requirement is different. I have a xml file and in that by using drag n drop I have to implement horiziontal scrollview, like I have a huge table which I have to show it horizontally and add textViews horizontally side by side. How can I achieve this?

Comment: what you have tried so far ? show your code

Answer (score 0):

Following code worked for me

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".SplashScrren" >

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Upload Your Image"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Upload Your Image"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Upload Your Image"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Upload Your Image"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Upload Your Image"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Upload Your Image"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Upload Your Image"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Upload Your Image"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Upload Your Image"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Upload Your Image"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Upload Your Image"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Upload Your Image"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Upload Your Image"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Upload Your Image"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Upload Your Image"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Upload Your Image"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Upload Your Image"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Upload Your Image"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Upload Your Image"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Upload Your Image"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Upload Your Image"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```